# Plane foliation with compact leaf must have a singularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, foliations

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Camacho & Neto's book $\textit{Geometric Theory of Foliations}$:

> Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a $C^r$ $(r\geq1)$ $1$-dimensional foliation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2/\mathscr{F}$ be the projection onto the leaf space of $\mathscr{F}$.
>
> (a) Prove that all the leaves of $\mathscr{F}$ are closed, but that $\mathscr{F}$ has no compact leaves.

How can I show that there is no compact leaf? I believe the idea is to suppose that there is such a compact leaf $F$, conclude that it must be diffeomorphic to $S^{1}$ and then use Poincaré-Bendixson theorem on the vector field associated to the line field $P$ defined by the foliation in order to find a singularity. However, PB theorem asks for some regularity on the vector field and, if we just construct the vector field this way, we might not have any sort of regularity.

I also believe that the idea at this point is to go to the orientable double covering of $P$ and there apply Poincaré-Bendixson, but I really don't see how to do this. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You've assumed the foliation is $C^r$, so doesn't that give you the regularity you need on the vector field?

Comment: @LeeMosher, more or less: since $\mathcal{F}$ is $C^{r}$ for $r\geq 1$, it could be that the line field associated to it (and hence the vector field) is only of class $C^{0}$ (specifically when $r=1$). Right?

Comment: If $\mathcal F$ is $C^r$ then it's line field should be $C^{r-1}$. So you just choose $r$ large enough to satisfy whatever regularity you need.